# Failed to build iOS app using Flutter run command or running from VSCode

Tags: ios, flutter

I tried to run my flutter project on iOS simulator, but I face with the following "meaningless" error. Can anyone know what I should do?

My Flutter version: v3.0.1
XCode Version: 13.3

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (3rd generation) in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           10.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-05-27 11:50:55.343 xcodebuild[26648:2506961] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-05-27 11:50:55.343 xcodebuild[26648:2506961] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/00/r0s0tm0x1s33__6xjw2fml1r0000gn/T/flutter_tools.p2wZ4e/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirRzZNzl/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    Failed to package /Users/****/Projects/ES.Online.Mobile.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/****/Projects/ES.Online.Mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/****/Projects/ES.Online.Mobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/00/r0s0tm0x1s33__6xjw2fml1r0000gn/T/flutter_tools.p2wZ4e/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirRzZNzl/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation).
Exited
```

Comment: You need to set the deployment target of your app to 9.0=>.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run it from Xcode first.

1. Start Xcode
2. Run your app from Xcode
3. After that stop the app from Xcode and try to run it from android studio or vscode.